# Alternative for the 'system settings' application?

Tags: kde, system-settings, i3-wm

Is there a "good" alternative application for the system settings application that comes with Ubuntu?

I mean I know that KDE and gnome come with their alternatives, but I would like to have one without having to install full KDE or gnome or too many background libraries.

Basically I need something to use with i3wm. Until 15.10 system-settings worked fine in i3wm but in 16.04 system settings display only 3 items.

Is there at least a way to install kde system settings without installing KDE as a dependency?

When launching unity-control-center with gksudo I get all the icons, but I don't get any sound devices. The terminal displays this error when I enter the sound menu:
(unity-control-center:15613): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: Unable to find stream for bar '(null)'
eoSink'

Comment: Which settings should be covered? KDE `systemsettings` covers quite a lot , when run from a fully installed KDE, but much of it is KDE specific (themes, autostart, …) or will not work (easily) work with `i3` because it will not be loaded by default (screen saver, power settings, …).

Comment: Well, at least the basics like sound, mouse, keyboard and other settings.

Answer (score 2):

Running `sudo unity-control-center` seems to show all icons.

There is a problem with this, though: no devices are listed in the Sound settings.